# How use subprocess.run with cmd external program in phython

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

I need to use this cmd command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\signtool.exe" verify /pa "C:\Program Files (x86)\myprogram\bin\aaa.exe"
```

in subprocess.run with python.
I try:

```
subprocess.run("cmd", "/c","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\signtool.exe"verify /pa "C:\Program Files (x86)\myprogram\bin\aaa.exe")
```

but not work.
What is the correct form for this command to work?

Comment: The first argument to `subprocess.run` should be a list. You will also need to escape the backslashes in the command line.

Comment: I try:
subprocess.run(["cmd, /c"],-1,"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/10.0.22621.0/x64/signtool.exe verify /pa C:/Program Files (x86)/myprogram/bin/aaa.exe")      
but not work, what i'm wrong?

Comment: You have already made an error before even starting. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\signtool.exe" verify /pa "C:\Program Files (x86)\myprogram\bin\aaa.exe"` is 100% not a "cmd command" and does not require to be "run with cmd". All you should be doing is running `signtool.exe` and passing it the arguments `verify /pa "C:\Program Files (x86)\myprogram\bin\aaa.exe"`.

Comment: if I run:
subprocess.run(["signtool.exe"]), compare this error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: You should always provide a full path to executables in a script. As you'd already done that in your examples, I didn't think I'd have to type out the ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\``` part too!

Comment: The [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) is on Windows a Python wrapper module to call the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with a filled out [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure. That is exactly the same function called by `cmd.exe` for running an executable. There is absolutely no need to run first `cmd.exe` just to run `signtool.exe`.

Comment: Please read the Python documentation for [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals). A backslash in a string enclosed in `"` must be escaped with one more backslash. `subprocess.run(["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\10.0.22621.0\\x64\\signtool.exe", "verify", "/pa", "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\myprogram\\bin\\aaa.exe\""])` could be better (not tested by me).

Comment: now it works!
this is correct form: subprocess.run(["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\10.0.18362.0\\x64\\signtool.exe", "verify", "/pa", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TeamViewer\\TeamViewer.exe"])
thank you for all!